# Modify DateTime on Month short name formatted date string

Tags: php

I'd like to use the datetime->modify function on a date string that's formatted like "21 Jan 2016". When I use the datetime->modify and add 1 day, it gives me a result of 30 Apr 2017. I know that if I don't use the short month name and use a number instead (i.e. 01), it will work fine but I would like to get it work this way with short month name. Is this possible?

Please see code below:

```
<?php
$date = "21 Jan 2016"; //  this is my date string
$newdate = new DateTime($date ); 
$date2 = $newdate->modify('+1 day'); // add 1 day to date string
echo $date2->format("d-M-Y"); 
?>
```

RESULT is:

30-Apr-2017

RESULT WANTED

22-Jan-2016

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to create a DateTime object from a non-ISO format. That's that part that is not working.

Take a look at: http://php.net/manual/ro/datetime.createfromformat.php

You will need to have something like

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('d M Y', '21 Jan 2016');
```

Full example:

```
$tomorrow = DateTime::createFromFormat('d M Y', '21 Jan 2016')->modify('+1 day')->format("d-M-Y");
echo($tomorrow);
```

Comment: when i use this: new DateTime::createFromFormat('DD M YY', '21 Jan 2016') i get  syntax error, unexpected 'createFromFormat' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$'

Comment: You need the "new DateTime" just "DateTime"

Comment: @lucian.nicolaescu it seems that when i do that, the modify doesn't work. Call to a member function modify() on a non-object

Comment: I've updated the answer, it seems that @Hatchet gave me the wrong format :). It should work now, I've tested it.

Answer (score 0):

The format of the `$date` variable is incorrect. Off the top of my head, there are two easy ways to fix this:

- Set `$date = "Jan 21, 2016"`
- Set `$date = "21-Jan 2016"`
- More options: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php

Your date format was wrong. That's all.